# Issue with trying to delete Firebase Firestore document field with update from flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete an item from an array using **FieldValue.arrayRemove()** in Flutter/Dart, but I'm getting a Firebase error that says:

> FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Invalid field path ([object Object]). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.

I'm not sure what's causing the error, but I think it might be because my array contains a string with one of these characters.

Here's my Flutter/Dart code:

```
// Delete document
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection('images')
    .doc(widget.id)
    .update(
  {
    'outputs': FieldValue.arrayRemove(
      ['/output/0/1f03f210.png'],
    ),
  },
);
```

[image]

Am I doing this correctly, and is there a workaround for this error?

**2/22/23 Update:**

I am not sure why but I create a dummy document in Firebase Firestore with a simple string and value without any of the characters that could possibly cause this error but I am still getting the error just for simply trying to update the field.

My current workaround involves getting the array locally, finding the index I want to remove, then using **.set({}, SetOptions(merge:true));**

I would like to know why I cant seem to update any field without seeing this error.

Environment:

- cloud_firestore: ^4.0.5
- Flutter version 3.8.0-13.0.pre.50 on channel master
- Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-240.0.dev)
- Chrome Web
- - debug_option_2 (release mode)
- - web-renderer html

**Current workaround:**

```
Future deleteImage(Map imageMap) async {
  String singleOutput = imageMap['output'];

  DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('images')
      .doc(widget.id);

  DocumentSnapshot docFields = await docRef.get();
  if (docFields.exists) {
    Map? docData = docFields.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (docData.containsKey('outputs')) {
      if (docData['outputs'].length <= 1) {
        docRef.delete();
      } else {
        List<dynamic> myArray = docData['outputs'];
        int index = myArray.indexOf(singleOutput.toString());
        myArray.removeAt(index);
        docRef.set({
          'outputs': myArray,
        }, SetOptions(merge: true));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the value you specify is being interpreted as a field path, which indeed can't contain `/` characters.

You might want to try wrapping it in a [`FieldPath` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath-class.html). If I read the docs correctly, that should be something like:

```
FieldValue.arrayRemove(
  [FieldPath.fromString('/output/0/1f03f210.png')],
),
```

Comment: This still causes the same error :(